# How do I resolve Error 2062: "No mapping specified..." in a project with no persistent data?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6

I have created an entity data model. I get this warning in Visual Studio:

```
Error 2062: No mapping specified for instances of the EntitySet and AssociationSet in the EntityContainer Model1Container.
```

I know I can resolve this warning by creating a database and mapping the entities to tables in the database. However, my project requires no persistent data, so a database would seem to be superfluous. How, then, do I resolve the warning?